# sqlite locked and SQL logic error or missing database

Tags: sqlite

I have a process that is steadily inserting into a sqlite db, using hibernate.
Everything works fine if I leave it alone.
If however, I start a sqlite3 session to the db file and run a query, I immediately get a "sqlite LOCKED" exception in my inserting process.
First off, this is contrary to sqlite docs, which says LOCKED is only internal. 
In any case, once I get the error, I catch the exception and move on the next insert.
And I close my external sqlite session.
But going forward, when I try to commit, it hangs for a long time, many minutes - and then I finally get

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: SQL logic error or missing database
```

The sqlite db is still very much there.
Why would I get this error?
Also, any way I can get rid of the LOCKED error - I dont have this issue with other databases when I have multiple sessions - why only sqlite?

Comment: This is a [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).

Comment: CL - Thanks. But as mentioned, the FAQ says I should get a BUSY exception - but I get LOCKED exception. And I can still live with that. What happens after - as described - is worse.